# How to tell Apache httpd 2.4.6 to not proxypass a particular path?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, rundeck

I am using apache to reverse proxy Rundeck. Rundeck has an API accessible at `rundeck.dns/api/`, as well as a web UI available at `rundeck.dns/{long list of other possible paths, such as user,menu,project}`.

As part of my reverse proxy, I am connecting to a RedHat SSO server to pass on user headers to rundeck. This is used for connecting to the UI. When accessing the API, I use a previously generated authtoken in my url.
Therefore, I need apache to NOT proxy my /api path at all. I have tried multiple configurations, including LocationMatch, with no results. The current configuration that I have allows UI access, but fails with the API, telling me:
"We're sorry, Kerberos is not set up. You cannot login."
It is worth noting that I have no kerberos configured anywhere, and that this error may not be an a apache one, rather a rundeck or RHSSO issue, but since Rundeck is not configured with any mention of the kerberos, I am assuming I am just making a mistake in apache.
My relevant current configuration in my site.conf is:

```
<Location />
AuthType openid-connect
  require valid-user

RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-User" %{REMOTE_USER}s

ProxyPass http://{rundeck IP}
ProxyPassReverse http://{rundeck IP}
</Location>

<Location /api>
</Location>
```

I have tried adding a `!` to a new ProxyPass for /api but that cannot be set inside a `<Location>`. On setting it at the outside the `<Location>`, I get a "Parameter must be in the form 'key=value'".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has been said before in many places, still, to make exceptions to proxy just append a ! at the end of the proxypass directive instead of specifying a target:

```
ProxyPass /path !
```

PS: Better to not place ProxyPass directives inside Location directives, that tends to complicate things (Location, ProxyPass directices are interpreted in opposite order and proxypass first parameter can already be a location so why complicate it)

Comment: As written in the question I cannot simply add a `!` due to being inside a Location. Setting it outside the Location results in a different error.

Comment: as I said, placing proxypass directives in locations is just complicating your life. Move it out.